# Request unit limit in Cosmos DB Sql API

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-data-factory, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I'm using ADF pipeline for storing data from data lake into cosmos db sql api. On triggering pipeline run, I see the following error:

[image]

Currently I'm using Throughput 5000 RU/s for the cosmos db container. Please help me understand why it is showing this error?

[image]

Here is my pipeline:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For saving your cost, don't unlimited increase RUs setting of cosmos db. Based on the error message you provided in your answer,it indicates that cosmos db can't process so many rows in unit time. So i suggest you throttling the transfer data procedure. Please consider using below configuration for the sink dataset of your copy activity.

[image]

The default value is 10,000, please decrease the number here if you do not concern the speed of transmission.More details ,please refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-cosmos-db#azure-cosmos-db-sql-api-as-sink).

[image]

Additional, you could throttling the max concurrent connections:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I don't use a copy activity. Where should I update the settings?

Comment: Also, should I reduce the size of batch size for fixing this?

Comment: @user3693060 Yes.You could try to reduce batch size. You said you don't use copy activity? Then how you transfer data?

Comment: I see LookUp & Mapping Data Flow. In the data flow, I use Sink to export data.